# what happens when aarch64 assembly kernel code terminates?

Tags: qemu, arm64

I am writing a kernel for a raspi3 and simulating it with QEMU4.0.0

I know that when writing a kernel, you usually have forever looping code. In my case I spinlock 3 out of 4 of my emulated raspi3 cores with:

```
1:   wfe
     b    1b
```

And in the main C program I have my last core running a `while(1)` loop where it just echoes stdin keystrokes

However, it occurred to me that the reason to spinlock cores is so that they don't execute code they shouldn't, i.e. code further down the Aarch64 assembly kernel file. Couldn't I just send the cores to the end of the file, where no more instructions exist to be run?

```
1:
//EOF
```

I tried this, and it compiled and ran (at least in QEMU4.0.0), but now I am curious as to what exactly happens when the instruction pointer finds nothing more to do.

What happens when the core reaches the end of the assembly file? Does it stop? Does it start reading whatever is next in memory? Is the emulator smarter than I am and handles it for me in a way real hardware wouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUs run code from memory, not from files. If the CPU "falls off" the end of a program that was loaded into memory, it will start attempting to execute code from the memory following your program. Since this memory will probably not contain valid code, the processor is likely to throw an invalid instruction exception. However, it is also possible that the data following your program *will* coincidentally be valid code, and that code may cause the system to behave unpredictably -- so adding a spin loop at the end of your program is a good idea.

Comment: For AArch64 in particular, the all-zero-bytes instruction is a (guaranteed) undefined instruction, and QEMU zero-initializes empty RAM, so what will happen here is that we'll take an undefined-instruction exception. If the guest kernel image didn't put anything useful at that exception entry point we will likely go into an endless loop of taking exceptions. You can confirm this by using QEMU's debug options or its gdb stub to see what the guest execution actually does.